# Suitecrm after install login page displays js code

Tags: php, suitecrm

After fresh install it redirect to login page `http://localhost/crm/index.php?module=Users&action=Login` but the one getting displayed is this jquery code

`YAHOO.util.Event.onDOMReady(function() {if(location.href.indexOf('print=true')>-1) setTimeout("window.print();",1000);});SUGAR.measurements={"breakpoints":{"x-small":750,"small":768,"medium":992,"large":1130,"x-large":1250}};SUGAR.loaded_once=false;$(document).ready(function(){loadSidebar();$("ul.clickMenu").each(function(index,node){$(node).sugarActionMenu();});$('#backtotop').click(function(event){event.preventDefault();$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0},500);});});YAHOO.util.Event.onAvailable('sitemapLinkSpan',function(){document.getElementById('sitemapLinkSpan').onclick=function(){ajaxStatus.showStatus(SUGAR.language.get('app_strings','LBL_LOADING_PAGE'));var smMarkup='';var callback={success:function(r){ajaxStatus.hideStatus();document.getElementById('sm_holder').innerHTML=r.responseText;with(document.getElementById('sitemap').style){display="block";position="absolute";right=0;top=80;} document.getElementById('sitemapClose').onclick=function(){document.getElementById('sitemap').style.display="none";}}} postData='module=Home&action=sitemap&GetSiteMap=now&sugar_body_only=true';YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest('POST','index.php',callback,postData);}});function IKEADEBUG(){var moduleLinks=document.getElementById('moduleList').getElementsByTagName("a");moduleLinkMouseOver=function(){var matches=/grouptab_([0-9]+)/i.exec(this.id);var tabNum=matches[1];var moduleGroups=document.getElementById('subModuleList').getElementsByTagName("span");for(var i=0;i0&&groupTabLeft>0){if(subTabHalfLength>=groupTabLeft){left=1;}else{left=groupTabLeft-subTabHalfLength;}} if(totalLengthInTheory>bw){var differ=totalLengthInTheory-bw;left=groupTabLeft-subTabHalfLength-differ-2;} if(left>=0){menuHandle.style.marginLeft=left+'px';}} YAHOO.util.Event.onDOMReady(function(){if(document.getElementById('subModuleList')){var parentMenu=false;var moduleListDom=document.getElementById('moduleList');if(moduleListDom!=null){var parentTabLis=moduleListDom.getElementsByTagName("li");var tabNum=0;for(var ii=0;iidiv'),currMenuBar;this.allMenuBars={};for(var i=0;i980&&$('.sidebar').is(':visible')){$('#bootstrap-container').addClass('col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main');}});function loadSidebar(){if($('#sidebar_container').length){$('#buttontoggle').click(function(){$('.sidebar').toggle();if($('.sidebar').is(':visible')){$.cookie('sidebartoggle','expanded');$('#buttontoggle').removeClass('button-toggle-collapsed');$('#buttontoggle').addClass('button-toggle-expanded');$('#bootstrap-container').addClass('col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2');$('footer').removeClass('collapsedSidebar');$('footer').addClass('expandedSidebar');$('#bootstrap-container').removeClass('collapsedSidebar');$('#bootstrap-container').addClass('expandedSidebar');} if($('.sidebar').is(':hidden')){$.cookie('sidebartoggle','collapsed');$('#buttontoggle').removeClass('button-toggle-expanded');$('#buttontoggle').addClass('button-toggle-collapsed');$('#bootstrap-container').removeClass('col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar');$('footer').removeClass('expandedSidebar');$('footer').addClass('collapsedSidebar');$('#bootstrap-container').removeClass('expandedSidebar');$('#bootstrap-container').addClass('collapsedSidebar');}});var sidebartoggle=$.cookie('sidebartoggle');if(sidebartoggle=='collapsed'){$('.sidebar').hide();$('#buttontoggle').removeClass('button-toggle-expanded');$('#buttontoggle').addClass('button-toggle-collapsed');$('#bootstrap-container').removeClass('col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar');$('footer').removeClass('expandedSidebar');$('footer').addClass('collapsedSidebar');$('#bootstrap-container').removeClass('expandedSidebar');$('#bootstrap-container').addClass('collapsedSidebar');} else{$('#bootstrap-container').addClass('col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2');$('#buttontoggle').removeClass('button-toggle-collapsed');$('#buttontoggle').addClass('button-toggle-expanded');$('footer').removeClass('collapsedSidebar');$('footer').addClass('expandedSidebar');$('#bootstrap-container').removeClass('collapsedSidebar');$('#bootstrap-container').addClass('expandedSidebar');}}} $(document).ready(function(){$('#alert-nav').click(function(){$('#alert-nav #alerts').css('display','inherit');});});function selectTab(tab){$('#content div.tab-content div.tab-pane-NOBOOTSTRAPTOGGLER').hide();$('#content div.tab-content div.tab-pane-NOBOOTSTRAPTOGGLER').eq(tab).show().addClass('active').addClass('in');};function changeFirstTab(src){var selected=$(src).attr('id');var selectedHtml=$(selected.context).html();$('#xstab0').html(selectedHtml);var i=$(src).parents('li').index();selectTab(parseInt(i));return true;} var getParameterByName=function(name,url){if(!url)url=window.location.href;name=name.replace(/[\[\]]/g,"\\$&");var regex=new RegExp("[?&]"+name+"(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),results=regex.exec(url);if(!results)return null;if(!results[2])return'';return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g," "));} var isUserProfilePage=function(){var module=getParameterByName('module');if(!module){module=$('#EditView_tabs').closest('form#EditView').find('input[name="module"]').val();} if(!module){if(typeof module_sugar_grp1!=="undefined"){module=module_sugar_grp1;}} return module=='Users';};var isEditViewPage=function(){var action=getParameterByName('action');if(!action){action=$('#EditView_tabs').closest('form#EditView').find('input[name="page"]').val();} return action=='EditView';};var isDetailViewPage=function(){var action=getParameterByName('action');if(!action){action=action_sugar_grp1;} return action=='DetailView';};var refreshListViewCheckbox=function(e){$(e).removeClass('glyphicon-check');$(e).removeClass('glyphicon-unchecked');if($(e).next().prop('checked')){$(e).addClass('glyphicon-check');} else{$(e).addClass('glyphicon-unchecked');} $(e).removeClass('disabled') if($(e).next().prop('disabled')){$(e).addClass('disabled')}};$(function(){if($('#bootstrap-container footer').length>0){var clazz=$('#bootstrap-container footer').attr('class');$('body').append(' '+$('#bootstrap-container footer').html()+' ');$('#bootstrap-container footer').remove();initFooterPopups();} var hideEmptyFormCellsOnTablet=function(){if($(window).width()<=767){$('div#content div#pagecontent form#EditView div.edit.view table tbody tr td').each(function(i,e){$(e).find('slot').each(function(i,e){if($(e).html().trim()==' '){$(e).html(' ');}});if($(e).html().trim()==' '){$(e).addClass('hidden');$(e).addClass('hiddenOnTablet');}});} else{$('div#content div#pagecontent form#EditView div.edit.view table tbody tr td.hidden.hiddenOnTablet').each(function(i,e){$(e).removeClass('hidden');$(e).removeClass('hiddenOnTablet');});}} $(window).click(function(){hideEmptyFormCellsOnTablet();setTimeout(function(){hideEmptyFormCellsOnTablet();},500);});$(window).resize(function(){hideEmptyFormCellsOnTablet();});$(window).load(function(){hideEmptyFormCellsOnTablet();});$(document).ready(function(){hideEmptyFormCellsOnTablet();});setTimeout(function(){hideEmptyFormCellsOnTablet();},1500);var listViewCheckboxInit=function(){var checkboxesInitialized=false;var checkboxesInitializeInterval=false;var checkboxesCountdown=100;var initializeBootstrapCheckboxes=function(){if(!checkboxesInitialized){if($('.glyphicon.bootstrap-checkbox').length==0){if(!checkboxesInitializeInterval){checkboxesInitializeInterval=setInterval(function(){checkboxesCountdown--;if(checkboxesCountdown<=0){clearInterval(checkboxesInitializeInterval);return;} initializeBootstrapCheckboxes();},100);}}else{$('.glyphicon.bootstrap-checkbox').each(function(i,e){$(e).removeClass('hidden');$(e).next().hide();refreshListViewCheckbox(e);if(!$(e).hasClass('initialized-checkbox')){$(e).click(function(){$(this).next().click();refreshListViewCheckbox($(this));});$(e).addClass('initialized-checkbox');}});$('#selectLink > li > ul > li > a, #selectLinkTop > li > ul > li > a, #selectLinkBottom > li > ul > li > a').click(function(e){e.preventDefault();$('.glyphicon.bootstrap-checkbox').each(function(i,e){refreshListViewCheckbox(e);});});checkboxesInitialized=true;clearInterval(checkboxesInitializeInterval);checkboxesInitializeInterval=false;}}};initializeBootstrapCheckboxes();};setInterval(function(){listViewCheckboxInit();},100);})`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and format the code. It's pretty much illegible. See also [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. PHP version installed is v8 which is not yet supported so I downgrade to PHP v7.4

Comment: See compatibility matrix before using product, in this case, here is the URL: https://docs.suitecrm.com/admin/compatibility-matrix/